# Using statement for android

Tags: java, xamarin

Do the using statement works for android? I am working in xamarin enviroment,and  i need to dispose some items. Xamarin allows me to use the using statement. Does this work for java language? Example:

```
using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(dpPath))
{
     mItems = db.Query<InventoryPreviewClass>("select * from InventoryPreviewClass where CategoryID =" + CategoryID + "");
     MyListViewAdapterInventory adapter = new MyListViewAdapterInventory(this, db, mItems);
     mlistview.Adapter = adapter;
}
```

Do i handle it with right way? Or it is safer on override destroy method to dispose all my elements? Example:

```
db = new SQLiteConnection(dpPath);

mItems = db.Query<InventoryPreviewClass>("select * from 
InventoryPreviewClass where CategoryID =" + CategoryID + "");
MyListViewAdapterInventory adapter = new 
MyListViewAdapterInventory(this, db, mItems);
mlistview.Adapter = adapter;


protected override void OnDestroy()
{
        base.OnDestroy();
        db.Dispose();
        db = null; 
}
```

I need to avoid memory leaks.
1) do i need to set db = null after dispose it?
2) Which is the best way for doing this? Also it is necessery? Or when i am calling finish my activity automatically destroys all my elements?

Comment: I am pretty sure that when destroy is called in an activity it calls the garbage collector which disposes of all the things in the activity, so idk do you even need this question in this case?

Comment: Thank you. So calling onDestroy() Method is useless right?

Comment: If you are calling destroy to manage memory or dispose or anything like that then no  its useless

Comment: Thank you G.hakim.

Comment: Rather manage all this in `OnLowMemory`

Comment: What you mean OnLowMemory ?

Comment: There is a method called `OnLowMemory` in native `Android Activities` which is called when your application is low on memory

Comment: No problem at all